# Migrating mysql db to heroku for web deployment

Tags: heroku, web-deployment, heroku-toolbelt, dbmigrate

Following on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25619794/deploy-my-app-on-heroku) question,

I have deployed my `php scripts` successfully to  `heroku`. Now I am having another doubt: How can I insert my local mysql db into heroku server?

On my local machine, I usually launch my db on `wamp server` and call `x.php` to initialize my app. I am wondering how I can do this on `heroku`?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku doesn't do MySQL per se, you would need to use a third-party add-on such as [ClearDB](https://addons.heroku.com/cleardb) or switch to Postgresql.